# C segmentation fault for no reason

Tags: c, cs50

I am taking edx's cs50 course and have run into a problem in my c code.
It gives me a segmentation fault for no obvious reason and all the other answers for this type of problem are too complicated for me to understand(I am a beginner)
It is a binary search function that will return true if it finds the value otherwise it will return false.
the code is as follows:

```
bool searchtruth(int vals[],int minimum, int maximum, int findval)
{
    int min = minimum;
    int max = maximum;
    if(min - max == 1 && (findval < max &&findval > min))
    {
        return false;
    }
    int mid = min + ((min - max) / 2);
    if(vals[mid] == findval)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(vals[mid] < findval)
    {
        return searchtruth(vals, mid , max, findval);
    }
    else if(vals[mid] > findval)
    {
        return searchtruth(vals, min , mid , findval);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you set `findval`?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also learn how to use a debuger.

Comment: Should `findval` be `find`?

Comment: I'd strongly advise to take a look at tools like Valgrind - they will help you in future. A lot.

Comment: Side note: Ask yourself how that final `else` is *ever* reached. Mental floss it. The only three comparative possible conditions are already covered prior. In fact, everything after the second `else if` could be removed, and simply replaced by `return searchtruth(vals, min , mid , findval);` Finally, this code is comparing values from the sequence `vals[]`, using `mid` as the index, computed from crunching `min` and `max`, but you're also comparing `findval` with `min` and `max` as if they were values, not indexes into `vals[]`. Pretty sure that's a bug too.

Comment: I think suspect the problem is in the code that calls this function. Segmentation faults come from misuse of pointers, and there are no pointers in this function.

Comment: Did you mean `mid = min + ((max - min) / 2);`?  You put `(min - max)`. And what is wrong with `mid = (min + max) / 2` anyway?

Comment: @WeatherVane in order of asked (a) undoubtedly, and (b) potential overflow on `max + min` (not likely, but never say never).

Comment: I agree with @Weather Vane. Place a "printf" function to check the  value of mid during every function call. The problem may be the unreasonable value of mid since it is used as index in your "vals" array

Comment: sorry abt that findval thing, I had edited it, now it is the original program.

Comment: @WhozCraig It was bugging out before that

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for pointing that out and I didnt think of the other one

Comment: Similarly `if(min - max == 1 ... )` is incorrect.

Comment: @WeatherVane I needed some sort of catch to end the recursion

Comment: Yes you do, and it needs to be `(max - min)` once again

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Ill test it and it will probably  work(IDK why I forget to catch that)

Comment: Yes, but please do not correct the posted code, it makes the dialog meaningless. Rolled back.

Comment: What are minimum and maximum supposed to represent? From the code, it looks like they are indices into the array. So why are you comparing findval to those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places in the code where you use

```
min - max
```

and in both places it should be

```
max - min
```

Comment: I'm upticking this because it is correct, regardless of what the now-morphed code looks like. (hate when that happens).

Comment: It is correct and I am sorry abt editing the code. Thanks